# Why is Vue 2 component not returning state for this computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, state, vuex

I have a Vue component that is failing to load because one of it's computed properties is undefined:

> Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

The computed property looks like this:

```js
artifacts() {
  let projectArtifacts;
  if (typeof this.currentProject !== 'undefined') {
    const { artifacts } = this.currentProject.settings.artifacts;
    projectArtifacts = Object.keys(artifacts).map((name) => ({
      value: name,
      labelText: this.convertValueToLabel(name),
    }));
  } else {
    projectArtifacts = this.MIQAConfig.artifact_options.map((name) => ({
      value: name,
      labelText: this.convertValueToLabel(name),
    }));
  }
  return projectArtifacts;
},
```

Looking at Vue's DevTools I can see under Vuex that the array I'm seeking is in the store:

```
state
 currentProject: Object
  settings: Object
   artifacts: Object
     Test One: -1
     Test Two: -1
```

I also have under `computed:`

```
...mapState([
  'currentProject',
]),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the object destructuring error

this expects that the `artifacts` object has another `artifacts` object in it

```js
const { artifacts } = this.currentProject.settings.artifacts;
```

use:

```js
const { artifacts } = this.currentProject.settings;
// or
const artifacts = this.currentProject.settings.artifacts;
```